# Flutter - failure while builing my first app with a virtual device using android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am learning Flutter with a course of Udemy. By using Android Studio, I tried to build my first app in a virtual device (Nexus 6) and I got this error message:

> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
>   Initializing gradle... Resolving dependencies...
>   * Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Mo\Desktop\Project\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited
>   abnormally: Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped
>   Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details Configure
>   project :app File C:\Users\Mo.android\repositories.cfg could not be
>   loaded. Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools
>   28.0.3 in C:\Users\Mo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in
>   C:\Users\Mo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses Warning: License for
>   package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\Mo\Desktop\Project\flutter_app\android\build.gradle' line:
>     24
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.    Failed
>     to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have
>     not been accepted.
>         build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
>         platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
>      To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>      Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see
>     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
>
>   Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Mo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 13s   Command:
>   C:\Users\Mo\Desktop\Project\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat
>   app:properties
>
> Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the
>   android/ folder.

I am grateful if anyone can help.
Thank you,

Comment: It says in the error "Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.". Run Flutter Doctor command. It should tell you what you are missing and how to solve it.

Comment: First, thank you for your comment. Indeed, I run Flutter Doctor and then the command flutter doctor --android-licenses. Then, I got this message :   Warning: File C:\Users\Mo\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
5 of 6 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...

Comment: Now the problem is resolved. I needed just to keep typing "y" as a yes to agree to all the licences. Thank you.